# How to properly read in a csv file and return data for use in other functions

Tags: python, csv, iteration

I am trying to read in a csv file using `read_csv()`, which I want to return an iterable list that can be used in other functions. The ultimate goal is to read in the columns from this file and pre-process it for use in `Weka`.

I'm having a hard time understanding how to get past this first step so I can actually start writing functions for feature extraction. I know the answer is probably simple, but I can't seem to get past this first point.

Tried using yield and generator, which only returns first line of the csvfile. Return only returned first line of csvfile.

```
import csv


    def read_csv():
        with open('spam.csv', newline='', encoding='latin-1') as csvfile:
            spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
            spamreader = list(spamreader)
            return spamreader


    def file_sort(spamreader):
        for row in spamreader:
            message = []
            stop_words = set(["the", "of", "a", "to", "be", "from", "or", ",", "'", "its", "is", "Is", "The", "To", "Its", "it's", "It's", "."])
            string = "".join(row[1])
            word_string = string.split()
            for word in stop_words:
                try:
                    while True:
                        word_string.remove(word)
                except ValueError:
                    pass
            for word in word_string:
                message.append(word)
        yield message


    def main():
        spamreader = read_csv()
        for message in file_sort(spamreader):
            print(message)
main()
```

Comment: What (and where) is the problem? It's unclear what you're asking...

Comment: It looks like you will only get a `message` from `file_sort` when the `for` loop completes. Indent your `yield message`

Answer (score 0):

It's important to realize that csv.reader parses the file as its read.  Python opens the file, iterates through it, and closes the file.  The object `spamreader` in your code is storing the event of the CSV file being read but not really creating a useful CSV data construct.

I think the easiest solution is to your problem is to convert the items from your CSV file into a list as they are read.  Python will then construct the list of lists you're looking for. Combine the 2nd and 3rd lines of your code into one statement:

```
with open('spam.csv', newline='', encoding='latin-1') as csvfile:
            spamreader = list(csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=','))
```

This will return a list of strings built from the CSV file (regardless of the internal data types).  If you want it to return numbers you'll need to use additional arguments.